# django oscar paypal redirect

Tags: django, redirect, paypal, django-oscar

I am using Django Oscar Paypal for payment. I am having an issue with redirecting back to my website on the production mode.

I have successfully set up in the development mode and I have tried two different IP address for runserver : 127.0.0.1:8000 and 192.168.1.102:8000 -> both worked corrected and redirected to whatever server I was running.

I turned off Sandbox mode and I have a website that has https:// working correctly. I try to make a payment on mywebsite.com/ but it redirects to https://192.168.1.102:8000/checkout/paypal/preview/13/?token=******* when I am redirected to paypal website for payment and click on Continue. (This happens for cancelling as well).

I have checked the views in the paypal app and it has 'reverse' code written correctly. If I paste /checkout/paypal/preview/13/?token=******* part after mywebsite.com/, it seems to be working correctly.

Is there a way to redirect back to mywebsite.com/

Many Thanks

Kyu

---

I just tried to switch to sandbox mode in the production but it doesn't redirect me to sandbox paypal! It keeps going to proper paypal payment site even with sandbox API... I am getting confused now.

Could this be because I haven't done python manage.py migrate and makemigrations?

Comment: hmm migrate / makemigrations didn't change anything

Answer (score 2):

Oscar uses the Django [sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/sites/) to determine the appropriate return URL.

You probably have the wrong domain (192.168.1.102) configured on your `Site`.

Edit the site from the admin (at `example.com/admin/sites/site/`) to set the domain that you use in production. Once you change this the redirect from Paypal should work.

Comment: It worked! I cant believe I spent hours and still couldnt figure out